# Handling JSON API response in PHP for data storage as variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, api, parsing

I need to store each individual value from the JSON API response as a variable so I can then store them in MySQL.

I am able to access the top level data shown here when echoing id, but cannot seem to access the nested data such as name>text.

I am new to API usage so any help is appreciated.

```
<?php
 include("restclient.php");



 $api = new RestClient(array(
    'base_url' => "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3", 
));
$result = $api->get("/events/" . $_POST['id_eventbrite'] . "/?token=MYTOKENISHERE");


echo $result['id'];


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Api result or json or xml, you should parse it. if json use `var_dump(json_decode($result, true));`
if xml use `json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($result)),true);`

Comment: It is coming from the Eventbrite API. I tried this and it just returns NULL. `<?php
 include("restclient.php");


 
 $api = new RestClient(array(
    'base_url' => "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3", 
));
$result = $api->get("/events/" . $_POST['id_eventbrite'] . "/?token=KEY");

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

echo $result['name']['text'];


?>`

Comment: Please do var_dump($result); and write result here.

Comment: It says there are too many characters. Basically, it is fetching the id correctly in my original code but will not display 2nd level fields. I am trying to display the event's title which is under name then text. Ex: `{"name": { "text:": THE EVENT TITLE},`

Comment: $res = json_decode($result, true); $title = $res['name]['text]; try this Hope its help you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a table with the corresponding columns of your Json result. Then you simply generate a query and place the values in place. For example, lets say your Json result is like this

- id : 1234
- name : Josh
- age : 25

You'll need to create the corresponding table

```
CREATE TABLE person ( id int, name varchar(25), age int);
```

The query would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

To bind the data, you'll do something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, name, age) VALUES(?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param($response['id'], $response['name'], $response['age']);
```

Then you execute the query and done.

For detailed information about parameter binding, check the php documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thank you, although my problem is not with the MySQL insertion. I am having trouble accessing the nested data. I can access the id fine but not the event title. Ex: `{"name": { "text:": THE EVENT TITLE},`

Comment: I see... In that case, use $myData=json_decode($YourJsonString, true); to get an array of your data... Then simply access it like an multidimensional array $myData['name']['text']